# Extracting GraphDistance out of SpatialGraphDistribution

Tags: graphs-and-networks, distance

I am trying to generate a graph which has Euclidean distances between the vertices. The documentation for `SpatialGraphDistribution` says that `SpatialGraphDistribution[v,maxd]` generates a distribution with `v` vertices which are at-most at a distance of `maxd` from each other.

```
g1 = RandomGraph[
  SpatialGraphDistribution[15, 0.15, 
   DistanceFunction -> (Norm[#2 - #1] &)], VertexLabels -> Automatic, 
  DirectedEdges -> True]

GraphDistance[g1, 8]
```

So, I do the above to generate a random graph with 15 vertices and a maximum Euclidean distance (or 2-norm) of 0.15 between them. Then, I test the generated graph by calculating the distance of vertex 8 from all other vertices but I get the following :

```
{\[Infinity], \[Infinity], 1, 2, \[Infinity], \[Infinity], \
\[Infinity], 0, \[Infinity], \[Infinity], \[Infinity], \[Infinity], \
\[Infinity], \[Infinity], \[Infinity]}
```

Can someone help me extract the correct Euclidean distances between the vertices? Also, for some reason `DirectedEdges -> True` does not work and I get undirected edges only.

Comment: `GraphDistance` is not Euclidean distance. It counts the number of "hops" you need to take to go from one vertex to another. When one vertex is not reachable from the other (disconnected graph), `GraphDistance` returns `Infinity`. If you want the Euclidean (geometric) distance, extract the vertex coordinates using `GraphEmbedding` and use `EuclideanDistance` or `DistanceMatrix`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood what you want exactly though. This post seems to be confounding graph distance with geometric distance. Can you clarify?

Comment: @Szabolcs I do want geometric distance. I was under the incorrect assumption that choosing to use a `Norm` as a `DistanceFunction` would automatically change `hops -> geometric distance`.

Comment: This is what `SpatialGraphDistribution` does: 1. it generates a bunch of points in space (by default, in 2D space). 2. The it uses the `DistanceFunction` to compute pairwise distances between them. 3. It connects points if their distance is smaller than the cutoff you've given.  The result is a graph. `GraphDistance` operates on the graph, not the geometric points.

Comment: @Szabolcs That's very helpful. Do you also know why `DirectedEdges -> True` results in an undirected graph in the above code?